# Существует ли какая-нибудь система измерений, согласно которой 1 килобайт = 1024 байт?

Tags: системы-счисления, байты

Узнал про гибибайты, начал копать и узнал, что 1 килобайт = 10^3 = 1000 байт.
Но 1024 байт = 1 кибибайт.

В школе, в универе и во многих статьях словами, связанными с байтом (килобайт, мегабайт и т.д.) оперируют как 2 в определенной степени, хотя [согласно СИ](https://www.bipm.org/utils/common/pdf/si-brochure/SI-Brochure-9-EN.pdf) это неправильно. Все, кто так пишут - просто неграмотные люди или есть какая-то система единиц/измерений, согласно которой 1 килобайт = 1024 байт, а не 1000 байт?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82

Comment: В килобайте 1024 байт. Это следует хотя бы из того, что микросхемы памяти (обычно) содержат число байт, кратное степени двойки. И так же из того, что полный двоичный (де)шифратор обслуживает адресное пространство опять же кратное кратное степени двойки.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 ничего ниоткуда не следует, это просто лично вам приспичило привязать приставку «кило» к степеням двойки просто так

Comment: @Serodv, напишите это как ответ, а не комментарий, чтобы я мог отметить его ответом на мой вопрос)